# IIS 7 to return Classic ASP as HTML

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic

I need IIS 7 to return a classic ASP request as basic text/html. This is for an internal application that will request the pages through ajax. The ASP code contains errors beyond the scope of this project, and prevents the request. I simply want to return the contents of the ASP page as though it were regular html, so that I can process the information in my application.

One thought was to apply on error resume next to all pages, but that would take too long. I've already tried deleting the Handler Mapping, or attempting to purposely limit the mapping by it's properties, but get an IIS 7 security error message.

If this could also be done against IIS 6 that would be great, but not required.

**UPDATE** To provide a better example of what I'm attempting to achieve: I managed to move forward on the project by completely uninstalling ASP from Windows Programs and Features in the control panel, then creating a MIME for .asp as "text/html". This works, but it takes down ASP for the entire server, so I had to re-enable it for other developers working on other projects. Is there no way to do this for one site, rather than the entire server's roles and responsibilities?

**POSSIBLE ANSWER**
For this site only, I updated the ASP Handler Mapping so that the asp DLL responds to ".aspdont". Then I added my own MIME type for .asp as "text/html". Seems a little sloppy, but given what I have to work with, that might be my only solution.

Comment: What is IIS doing with it now?

Comment: It attempts to process the ASP page and return the results. Because the ASP has errors, it returns 505 error code, and the error message.

Comment: That would mean updating around 10,000 pages.

Comment: Any chance of a meaningful chunk of code so I can reproduce the error on my local IIS 7? I worked hard on ASP classic a long, long time ago so I *might* be able to help if I have something to get my hands dirty with.

Comment: The ASP errors are basic and easy to fix, it's the quantity (as noted above). I am hoping to learn how to better understand and configure IIS 7 and how it handles file types. So to reproduce the error, create an ASP page, host it under IIS 7, place any ASP code block <%="hello world"%>, then attempt to get IIS 7 to send the page as-is, with the code block, without processing the page and sending just the output you would normally expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot disable Classic ASP for one site; you can only deny it, or uninstall it, at the server level. There are two possible workarounds: Move it to a new server without Classic ASP installed, or, at the site level, remap the handler for .asp to an unused extension, like .aspdont. Then, for either solution, create the MIME type at the site level for .asp as text/html. Now the pages will return ASP unprocessed.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the result of this ASP is dynamic ? Thus based on databasequeries etc ? Then you have no other option than either fix the error or skip the parts which produce the error. Even if you have a multitude of ASP pages (i suppose you exagerata a bit here), if you start with the first page (the one requesed by your ajax) it is simply a matter of commenting out all the references to other pages and just keep the ones you really need to produce the resulkt that your ajax-call needs.

Please publish your called ASP and the ajax call you are gonna throw at it so that we an give better advice.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, Peter. The number of pages is an estimate, but fairly accurate. It's a pseudo content management system, but rather than data stored in a database, the content is stored in ASP pages (don't get me started...). Thankfully, there are no database calls on the ASP pages; the error mostly derives from the application framework no longer existing, only the ASP files. So it cannot find several includes. I started to fix by creating fake include files, but there are so many calls to variables and methods defined in the includes that it keeps breaking.

Comment: given your adapted question the best way would be to convert your ASP data to a database and rebuild the entire thing from scratch, why don't you publish some relevant ASP, without it we won't be able to help i'm afraid

Comment: That's what we're attempting to do-- I built a little app that parses the content from all the ASP pages to place into a database. At least, that was the idea until I ran into this issue where IIS returned error messages rather than the page content. We decided to move the content to another web server that doesn't have ASP installed so this project can move forward. With ASP returning as part of the HTML, we can strip it out and save the content into the database.

Comment: asp is text that can easily be read and parsed from a file share, no need to take the web-approach